# How to remove action hooking non static method and class can not be instantiated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using woocommerce product vendors  plugin and in single product page there is sold by . I want to replace this  with ;

It is added like

```
class WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend {
    public static function init() {
        $self = new self();

        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $self, 'add_sold_by_single' ), 39 );
   return true;
   }
   public function add_sold_by_cart( $values, $cart_item ) {
        $sold_by = get_option( 'wcpv_vendor_settings_display_show_by', 'yes' );

        if ( 'yes' === $sold_by ) {

            $sold_by = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_sold_by_link( $cart_item['data']->id );

            $values[] = array(
                'name' => apply_filters( 'wcpv_sold_by_text', esc_html__( 'Sold By', 'woocommerce-product-vendors' ) ),
                'display' => '<em class="wcpv-sold-by-cart"><a href="' . esc_url( $sold_by['link'] ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $sold_by['name'] ) . '">' . $sold_by['name'] . '</a></em>',
            );
        }

        return $values;
    }
}
WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend::init();
```

I tried to unhook it like

1)

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_remove_actions', 39 );
function my_remove_actions(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend', 'add_sold_by_single' ), 39 );
}
```

2)

```
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_remove_actions', 39 );
function my_remove_actions(){
    global $wc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend;
    $wc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend = new WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend();

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $wc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend, 'add_sold_by_single' ), 39 );

}
```

3)

```
class XWC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend extends WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend{
    public function __construct(){}
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_remove_actions', 39 );
function my_remove_actions(){
    global $xwc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend;
    $xwc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend = new XWC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend();
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $xwc_product_vendors_vendor_frontend, 'add_sold_by_single' ), 39 );

}
```

4)

```
class XWC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend extends WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend{
        public function __construct() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'add_sold_by_single' ), 39 );

    }
}
new XWC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend();
```

5)

```
class XWC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend extends WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend{
            public static function init() {
            $self = new self();
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $self, 'add_sold_by_single' ), 39 );

        }
    }
XWC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend::init();
```

But could not remove this ! Please guide me to do this.

**Update**

I got output for

```
print_r($wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary']);

Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [woocommerce_template_single_price] => Array
                (
                    [function] => woocommerce_template_single_price
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [woocommerce_template_single_excerpt] => Array
                (
                    [function] => woocommerce_template_single_excerpt
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [woocommerce_template_single_meta] => Array
                (
                    [function] => woocommerce_template_single_meta
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [woocommerce_template_single_sharing] => Array
                (
                    [function] => woocommerce_template_single_sharing
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart] => Array
                (
                    [function] => woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [00000000262d19ef000000007f4708faadd_sold_by_single] => Array
                (
                    [function] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend Object
                                (
                                )

                            [1] => add_sold_by_single
                        )

                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )

            [le_child_add_sold_by_single] => Array
                (
                    [function] => le_child_add_sold_by_single
                    [accepted_args] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are the solutions not working for you?

In order to unregister a callback, you have to get the instance of the object.  The problem with this plugin is: it's not using a Singleton properly by giving you the means to grab the instance.  Therefore, you can't get the instance. Boo.

**Work Around**

We need a workaround.  Let me explain to help you in the future.

WordPress Core stores all of the registered callbacks with their events' registry.  When you do `add_action` or `add_filter`, the callback is being stored in this event registry table (which is a large multi-dimensional array).  In order to unregister (or remove) a callback that is a method within a specific object (and not a static method), you have to have the instance of the object.  That means you need the variable that represents the object you want to target.

Here in this example, you don't have that directly.  But WordPress stores the key to the method using it's object hash ID concatenated with the method name.  That pattern we can use to fetch the record (element) in the event registry table.

```
/**
 * #EXPLANATION#
 * The plugin loads the file using `plugins_loaded` with a priority of 0.  Here
 * we are doing the same thing but after the file is loaded, meaning after the
 * events are registered.
 */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_woocommerce_add_sold_by_single_callback', 1 );
/**
 * Unregister the WooCommerce `WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend::add_sold_by_single` from the
 * event `woocommerce_single_product_summary`.
 *
 * #EXPLANATION#
 * I'm adding comments in the code only to illustrate what is happening and why.  Please
 * remove the inline comments when using this code. Thank you.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function remove_woocommerce_add_sold_by_single_callback() {
    /**
     * #EXPLANATION#
     * WordPress keeps an event registry table for the callbacks that
     * are pre-registered to each event name.  The format of the table is:
     *
     * $wp_filter[ event name ][ priority number ][ callback name ]
     *
     * The registry table is a global variable called $wp_filter.  You need to include
     * that global into this function's scope.
     */
    global $wp_filter;

    /**
     * #EXPLANATION#
     * Let's make sure that the event name has a callback registered to the priority
     * number of 39. If no, then return early (bail out).
     */
    if ( ! isset( $wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary']['39'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * #EXPLANATION#
     * We will loop through each of the registered callbacks for the priority of 39. Why?
     * You can't assume that only that one function is registered at 39.  There may be more.
     * Therefore, let's loop.
     *
     * We are grabbing the callback function that is registered.  This is a unique key. For
     * objects, WordPress uses the PHP construct spl_object_hash() to grab its hash ID. Then it
     * concatenates it together with the method's name.  You are not going to know what the unique
     * ID is. Why? The first 32 characters are the hash ID, which is a memory location and not
     * relative to the human readable name of `WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend`.  Rather, it's
     * related to its object.
     */
    foreach( $wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary']['39'] as $callback_function => $registration ) {
        /**
         * #EXPLANATION#
         * Give that we don't know what the first 32 characters of the object's hash ID is, we need
         * to check if the callback function includes the method we are looking for.  This line
         * of code says: "Hey, do you contain the method name `add_sold_by_single` starting at
         * the 32's character."  If yes, then this is the one we want.
         */
        if ( strpos( $callback_function, 'add_sold_by_single', 32) !== false) {

            /**
             * #EXPLANATION#
             * Now we have the actual callback function key that is registered in the
             * event registry.  We can use remove_action to unregister it.
             */
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', $callback_function, 39 );

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially what this code is doing is this:

1. Checks if anything is already registered to the event name and priority number.  If no, there's nothing to do.  Let's bail out.
2. We need to get the unique ID, or as WordPress calls it, the `$idx`.  This is the callback's unique key, which is comprised of the hash ID . method name.
3. Once we have that unique ID, then you can unregister the callback using `remove_action`.  It works for `remove_filter` too.

**Reusable Code**

The code above was to illustrate how to do and how it works.  But that code is not reusable, since the parameters are hard coded.  Instead, you will want to use [this code](https://gist.github.com/hellofromtonya/7b6b6e1fdf13da3e05181f21865ddb78) and then call it like this (when in a plugin):

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_woocommerce_add_sold_by_single_callback', 1 );
/**
 * Unregister the WooCommerce `WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend::add_sold_by_single` from the
 * event `woocommerce_single_product_summary`.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function remove_woocommerce_add_sold_by_single_callback() {
    do_hard_unregister_object_callback( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 39, 'add_sold_by_single');
}
```

**Which Event?**

If you are using this code in a plugin (which you should be), use `plugins_loaded`.

If you put it into your theme, you can't use `plugins_loaded` because it already fired before the theme loaded.  For a theme, you need to use `after_setup_theme` instead of `plugins_loaded`.

**To Test**

To test, let's dump out the registry before and after to see if it did remove it.  Do the following:

```
function remove_woocommerce_add_sold_by_single_callback() {
    global $wp_filter;

    var_dump( $wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary'][39] );

    do_hard_unregister_object_callback( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 39, 'add_sold_by_single');

    if ( ! isset( $wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary'][39] ) ) {
        var_dump( $wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary'] );
    } else {
        var_dump( $wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary'][39] );
    }
}
```

The results will let us see if it was there to start and gone after.

Comment: You had put a really great effort, thank you so much for this, but even with this I could not make that unhooked !!!

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu At this point, you will need to debug why within your code.  Use XDebug and/or `var_dump` to tap in and see what is happening.  I'd suggest that you look at the `var_dump( $wp_filter );` before the `foreach` loop and then after `remove_action` runs.  Starting there will let you see what the unique ID is for the method.  It also validates for you the timing of everything, meaning is the callback in that plugin registered as expected.  You can post the results here and we can help you walk through the discovery process.

Comment: I have just added the output for `print_r($wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary']);` in my question.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Is this after the `remove_filter()` line of code or before?  We want to see it before and after.  Why?  Before shows us that it is registered.  After shows us if it unregistered.

Comment: I got this out put by printing it on `woocommerce_before_single_product` hook .

Comment: Yes, but when?  You have to run after you run `do_hard_unregister_object_callback()`.  You want to check it after you've unregistered it.  We want to see the result of running the code I gave to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128996/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-hellofromtonya).

Comment: It would be great if you can the same for how people can unhook multiple using this and if possible filters using this, it would be great .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_remove_actions' );
function my_remove_actions(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'WC_Product_Vendors_Vendor_Frontend', 'add_sold_by_single' ), 39 );
}
```

---

Show all hooked functions for this filter:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'lets_have_a_look' );
function lets_have_a_look(){        
    global $wp_filter;
    print_r($wp_filter['woocommerce_single_product_summary']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, but It did not worked :(

Comment: Maybe it helps if you show all hooked functions to this filter. See my updated answer.

Comment: yeh, your effort is helpful dear friend. :)

Comment: And lots of love and blessings to your cute child . :) <3

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do it by javascript.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', "move_author_summary_to_image");
/**
 * Move the author summary right after the image so we can float them left and right.
 */
function move_author_summary_to_image() {
?>
    <script>
    $('document').ready (function () {
        var summary = $("#isle_body .wcpv-vendor-profile.entry-summary").html();
        $("#isle_body .wcpv-vendor-profile.entry-summary").hide();
        $(summary).addClass("author_summary").insertAfter($("#isle_body p.wcpv-vendor-logo")); 

    });
    </script>
<?php
}
```